# SharePoint 2013 Webpart - Multiple file upload

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, splistitem, attachments

I want to add the multiple files functionality to my custom webpart in C# .NET 4.5.

I want the same functionality as the out of the box multiple files add feature when you create a list item via the user interface. (see image below)

[image]

I want to list all the files to be uploaded before I hit the 'Submit' button in my webpart.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AjaxFileUpload. Have a look at the demo on below link.

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ajaxFileUpload/ajaxFileUpload.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use plupload - its quite popular.
Demo: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2013/Mar/12/Using-plUpload-to-upload-Files-with-ASPNET

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below url its useful :
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sarav82/MOSS11072007065009AM/MOSS.aspx

OR

http://spupload.codeplex.com/